# Buttons and CheckBoxes don't appear in windows 32 bits (windows xp)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have developped an app for windows in windows 64 bits, but using .NET framework 3.5 however in Windows 32 bits, the buttons and checkboxes dont appear. Why?

Here is the print screen of my program running in windows 64 bits

[image]

and here is the print screen of my program running in windows 32 bits

[image]

Comment: To figure out the cause we're not going to be able to help you if we only see the result

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that this is a 32/64 bit issue. There are platform differences that affect rendering between different versions of windows (i.e. xp/win7) but 32/64. Not likely.

Comment: I have already explained that I have these checkbox and buttons with status Visible = true and It doesn't appear in Windows 32 bits..Need more info? Can quest me

Comment: @spender I have made in windows 7

Comment: I notice that the first image is 1920x1080 and the second is 1440x900... is it possible the checkboxes are simply further down, off the screen?

Comment: No, this is impossible because the checkboxes have width larger than images...if was this, the checkboxes corner appear

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave comments, unfortunately. As mentioned above, it's unlikely related to CPU/OS architecture. It's obvious you use different installations of OS, maybe it's different PC's. Any of it has it's own preferences. In general case, it's impossible to say why you don't see checkboxes. It can be paths issue, or security, or %anything%. Did you run your app under debugger? Did you get any exceptions or log entries? (if you have one)

Comment: I have only the executable file in the other computer...is not mine computer...I mean that is the architecture because in first time that I have tried to run in my other computer, I can't. I rebuild my application with .net FrameWork 3.5 and downloaded this in my other computer. Then, the application has opened but the buttons and checkboxes doesn't appear. It make no sense for me...therefore I mean that is the architecture

Comment: I ran the same application in others 2 computer, without which I developed and works fine

Comment: Take a look at @endofzero question. Also try to wrap your Application.Run(new MainForm()) with try/catch and show messagebox/write error to log. If it's code issue, you'll catch it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer for @endofzero question

Comment: Well, I can't help with anything else. If you stored your code somewhere in public repository, post it. Otherwise it's too hard to investigate what's wrong.